# Depth Search in Spark Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, depth

I've a following data which has user and supervisor relationship.

```
user |supervisor |id
-----|-----------|----
a    |   b       | 1
b    |   c       | 2
c    |   d       | 3
e    |   b       | 4
```

I want to explode the relationship hierarchy between the user and supervisor as below.

```
user |supervisor |id
-----|-----------|----
a    |   b       | 1
a    |   c       | 1
a    |   d       | 1
b    |   c       | 2
b    |   d       | 2  
c    |   d       | 3
e    |   b       | 4
e    |   c       | 4
e    |   d       | 4
```

As you see, for the user 'a', the immediate supervisor is 'b' but again 'b' has 'c' as its supervisor. So indirectly 'c' is supervisor for 'a' as well and so on. Such as, my aim is to explode the hierarchy at any level for a given user. What is the best way to implement this in spark-scala ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an approach using dataframes. I show doing one level of hierarchy, but it can be done multiple times by repeating the step below:

```
val df = sc.parallelize(Array(("a", "b", 1), ("b", "c", 2), ("c", "d", 3), ("e", "b", 4))).toDF("user", "supervisor", "id")
scala> df.show
+----+----------+---+
|user|supervisor| id|
+----+----------+---+
|   a|         b|  1|
|   b|         c|  2|
|   c|         d|  3|
|   e|         b|  4|
+----+----------+---+
```

Let's enable cross joins:

```
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.crossJoin.enabled", true)
```

Then join the same table:

```
val dfjoin = df.as("df1").join(df.as("df2"), $"df1.supervisor" === $"df2.user", "left").select($"df1.user", $"df1.supervisor".as("s1"), $"df1.id", $"df2.supervisor".as("s2"))
```

I use an udf to combine two columns into an array:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.udf
val combineUdf = udf((x: String, y: String) => Seq(x, y))
val dfcombined = dfjoin.withColumn("combined", combineUdf($"s1", $"s2")).select($"user", $"combined", $"id")
```

Then the last step is to flatten the array to separate rows and filter rows that did not join:

```
val dfexplode = dfcombined.withColumn("supervisor", explode($"combined")).select($"user", $"id", $"supervisor").filter($"supervisor".isNotNull)
```

The first level hierarchy looks like this:

```
scala> dfexplode.show
+----+---+----------+
|user| id|supervisor|
+----+---+----------+
|   c|  3|         d|
|   b|  2|         c|
|   b|  2|         d|
|   a|  1|         b|
|   a|  1|         c|
|   e|  4|         b|
|   e|  4|         c|
+----+---+----------+
```